# Issue to include wp-config.php file in wordpress plugin file

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I working on a plugin, in plugin i create an AJAX (in plugin index file) that when a user write something in search bar the related posts title shows in drop down and for get that result i create an other file for this like "foo_get_posts.php" in plugin root directory. Here is my code:

```
function foo_search_form(){
?>
    <div class="foo_search_field">
        <form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" class="clearfix" action="<?php echo home_url( '/' ); ?>" autocomplete="off">
            <input type="text" onfocus="if (this.value == '<?php _e("Search Posts...", "foo") ?>') {this.value = '';}" onblur="if (this.value == '')  {this.value = '<?php _e("Search Posts...", "foo") ?>';}" value="<?php _e("Search Posts...", "foo") ?>" name="s" id="s" />
            <ul id="foo_search_dropdown"></ul>
            <input type="hidden" name="post_type" value="foo_base" />
        </form>
    </div>
<?php
}

add_action('wp_head', 'foo_search_drop');
function foo_search_drop(){
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery('#s').keyup(function() {
            jQuery('#foo_search_dropdown').slideDown("slow");
            // Get data
            var foo_search_term = jQuery(this).val();

            // Sending data through AJAX to process
            jQuery.post('<?php echo plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) ?>foo_get_posts.php', {foo_search_key: foo_search_term}, function(data) {
                jQuery('#foo_search_dropdown').html(data);
            });
        });
    });
</script>
<?php
}
```

foo_get_posts.php file code:

```
<?php
require_once( str_replace('//','/',dirname(__FILE__).'/') .'../../../wp-config.php');

global $wpdb;
$foo_search_key = $_POST['foo_search_key'];
$tbl_posts = $wpdb->prefix."posts";
$tbl_relation = $wpdb->prefix."term_relationships";
$tbl_taxonomy = $wpdb->prefix."term_taxonomy";
$tbl_terms = $wpdb->prefix."terms";

if(!empty($foo_search_key)){
    $foo_search_sql = $wpdb->get_results(" // My SQL Query goes here");

    if($foo_search_sql){
        foreach ($foo_search_sql as $search_result) {
        ?>
            <li>
                <a href="<?php echo site_url()."/".foo_PLUGIN_SLUG."/".$search_result->post_name ?>">
                    <?php echo $search_result->post_title; ?>
                </a>
            </li>
            <?php
        }
    } else {
        ?>
            <span>Search result not found......</span>
<?php
    }
}
?>
```

First i don't call `require_once( str_replace('//','/',dirname(__FILE__).'/') .'../../../wp-config.php');` in my file, so i don't get my results, so i ask a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24773312/wordpress-global-wpdb-function-issue) for this and now my work goes perfectly.

### Problem

Now my plugin is complete and i send it to wordpress and they reject it, they say:

```
## Calling core loading files directly

You're calling this in foo_get_posts.php

require_once( str_replace('//','/',dirname(__FILE__).'/') .'../../../wp-config.php');

Including wp-config.php, wp-blog-header.php, wp-load.php, or pretty much any other WordPress core file that you have to call directly via an include is not a good idea and we cannot approve a plugin that does so unless it has a very good reason to load the file(s). It is prone to failure since not all WordPress installs have the exact same file structure.

Usually plugins will include wp-config.php or wp-load.php in order to gain access to core WordPress functions, but there are much better ways to do this. It's best if you tie your processing functions (the ones that need but don't have access to core functions) into an action hook, such as "init" or "admin_init".
```

I also try move this file "foo_get_posts.php" in theme and call header and footer but it gives me error, so i reverted my work.

If i remove this line `require_once( str_replace('//','/',dirname(__FILE__).'/') .'../../../wp-config.php');` from my file i don't get my DB results, so it is neccessry for me.

So please tell me how can i resolve this issue, please help me.

Comment: why did you included wp-config.php? you already connect with wpdb without including it

Comment: I don't know why $wpdb firstly get results ....but when i call this file my sql query is work perfectly

Comment: remove require_once(  wp-config.php from this file and check

Comment: o my brother i already checked to remove this line, but my sql query not working :(

Comment: is this file same with name of your plugin? if different include file into that

Comment: No, for example my plugin name is wp_articles and my file name is foo_get_posts.php

Comment: The message from the Wordpress team is pretty clear. There's no reason to call core files directly, as the plugin is already in the The Loop and has access to Wordpress functionality.

Comment: but why not my "foo_get_posts.php" file not work without calling wp-config.php

Answer (score 1):

As per wordpress document,, if your Plugin will be called "Fabulous Functionality", you might call your PHP file fabulous-functionality.php. So first create that file and include other files

Comment: can you give me the wordpress document for fabulous-functionality.php file

Comment: you can get documentation about plugin here http://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin

Comment: Have you check it? any query in it? change as per document and test plugin

Comment: this link can not help me

Comment: it's not just hint. you have to create file as per plugin name and include other files into it.